# Accessing and modifying ArrayList/TreeSet in a Class from multiple Classes

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am new to java and I am trying to access a ArrayList and TreeSet that are in different classes from other classes.
I know this way of accessing it from one class.

This is the class were I have my TreeSet:

```
 public class Gestor {
        private TreeSet<User> gestorTSusers;

        public Gestor (){
            this.gestorTSusers = new TreeSet<>();
        }          

        public TreeSet<User> getGestorTSusers() {
            return gestorTSusers;
        }

        public void setGestorTSusers(TreeSet<User> gestorTSusers) {
            this.gestorTSusers = gestorTSusers;
        }
    }
```

For now I know that I need something like this to have access to my TreeSet on another class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    private ArrayList<Obj> ts;
    private Gestor gestor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViews();

        gestor = new Gestor();

        gestor.getGestorTSusers()...                 
    }

    private void findViews() {
        this.tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        this.tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        this.tv3 = findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    }
}
```

Above here I am creating a new Gestor to have access to the `TreeSet` inside, but now I want to have access to the **same exact** `TreeSet` I am working here but in a different class. If I just do like

```
private Gestor gestor;
this.gestor.get....
```

Am I working with the same `TreeSet`?
Will the **Context** be useful somehow?
What is the best and most efficient way to do something like this?

I'm sorry I know this looks terrible but it's my first time asking so give me a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you only would want one instance of Gestor, and use it in multiple classes. When you make Gestor a singleton and you'll have same TreeSet<...> instance tied to Gestor. Try to understand what a singleton design pattern mean here, https://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html.

Comment: I saw the link and it seemed like a solution, but I believe it's not the best one. I will do more research but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the treeSet in your gestor object like below.

```
Gestor gestor = new Gestor();
gestor.setGestorTSusers(treeSetYouWantToUse)
```

You could also make a constructor in your Gestor class that takes the tree set

```
public class Gestor {
        private TreeSet<User> gestorTSusers;

        public Gestor (TreeSet treeSetYouWantToUse){
            this.gestorTSusers = treeSetYouWantToUse;
        }          

        public TreeSet<User> getGestorTSusers() {
            return gestorTSusers;
        }

        public void setGestorTSusers(TreeSet<User> gestorTSusers) {
            this.gestorTSusers = gestorTSusers;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that the TreeSet I want to use is the one I create in Gestor class (`gestorTSusers`), so it would not make sense to set the treeset to itself. Pretty much same thing with the constructor. Do you understand where I wanna get here? If I am missing something please tell me and thanks for the feedback

Comment: I see now.  I like the singleton from @Juseeth but if you don't want that you can have a getter in your MainActivity class to return `this.gestor` or `this.gestor.getGestorTSusers()`

Comment: you mean a public method that returns the arrayList `gestorTSusers` of the instance that I create in MainActivity? And then I could send back the updated Array to the MainActivity and pass it through another method that would update my actuall ArrayList in Gestor Class?